# Changing the cell color in an ultragrid with the columns key and for each

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, infragistics

My goal is to color the exactly same cell as i have already colored, but just one column before. I tried do it with the index but that didn't work out. I got a hint that i should do it with the Key property but i can't figure out how. Here is what i tried:

```
For Each column As UltraGridColumn In ugResult.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns

                If column.Key = "K_Art" Or column.Key = "UANR" Or column.Key = "Ueberbegriff" Or column.Key = "Benennung" Or column.Key = "Anzahl" Or column.Key = "Einheit" Or column.Key = "Einzelkosten" Or column.Key = "Sumcode" Or column.Key = "Status" Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value IsNot Nothing Then

                        e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        e.Row.Cells(column.Index - 1).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    End If

                End If
            Next
```

Any help in c# and vb.net is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
For Each column As UltraGridColumn In ugResult.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns
                Select Case column.Key
                    Case "K_ArtCompare"
                        If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            e.Row.Cells("K_Art").Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        Else
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value = e.Row.Cells("K_Art").Value
                        End If
                    Case "UANR_Compare"
                        If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            e.Row.Cells("UANR").Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        Else
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value = e.Row.Cells("UANR").Value
                        End If
                    Case "UeberbegriffCompare"
                        If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            e.Row.Cells("Ueberbegriff").Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        Else
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value = e.Row.Cells("Ueberbegriff").Value
                        End If
                    Case "BenennungCompare"
                        If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            e.Row.Cells("Benennung").Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        Else
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value = e.Row.Cells("Benennung").Value
                        End If
                    Case "AnzahlCompare"
                        If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value <> -1 Then
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            e.Row.Cells("Anzahl").Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        Else
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value = e.Row.Cells("Anzahl").Value
                        End If
                    Case "EinheitCompare"
                        If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            e.Row.Cells("Einheit").Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        End If
                    Case "EinzelkostenCompare"
                        If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value <> -1 Then
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            e.Row.Cells("Einzelkosten").Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        Else
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value = e.Row.Cells("Einzelkosten").Value
                        End If
                    Case "SummencodeCompare"
                        If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            e.Row.Cells("Sumcode").Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        Else
                            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value = e.Row.Cells("Sumcode").Value
                        End If
                End Select

            Next
    End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
For Each column As UltraGridColumn In ugResult.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns
     If column.Key = "K_Art" Or column.Key = "UANR" Or column.Key = "Ueberbegriff" Or column.Key = "Benennung" Or column.Key = "Anzahl" Or column.Key = "Einheit" Or column.Key = "Einzelkosten" Or column.Key = "Sumcode" Or column.Key = "Status" Then
           Exit For
     Else
           If e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                e.Row.Cells(column.Index).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                e.Row.Cells(column.Index - 1).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
         End If
     End If
Next
```

Comment: No, it doesnt. It colors the whole column two indexes back.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the value of the cell with `DbNull.Value` like this:

```
For Each column As UltraGridColumn In ugResult.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns
    If column.Key = "K_Art" Or column.Key = "UANR" Or column.Key = "Ueberbegriff" Or column.Key = "Benennung" Or column.Key = "Anzahl" Or column.Key = "Einheit" Or column.Key = "Einzelkosten" Or column.Key = "Sumcode" Or column.Key = "Status" Then
        Exit For
    Else
        If Not DbNull.Value.Equals(e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Value) Then
            e.Row.Cells(column.Key).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            e.Row.Cells(column.Index - 1).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why? The if statement works fine, problem is that (column.Index - 1) doesn't work

Comment: to answer why (column.Index - 1) we need to know the structure of your columns. BTW did you test this with (column.Index) instead of (column.Key)?

Comment: Yes, i did. I found a solution, i'll post it here.